# How do I remove MS Outlook Express from a PC?

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express

Is there any way to completely uninstall MS Outlook Express from a PC running Windows XP?

Comment: From your comment to nik's answer - are you talking about Outlook or Outlook Express? They are two separate products.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I meant OE. Questioned now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're referring to Outlook Express rather than Outlook (confusingly they are two completely separate products) I've found some information on how to do that:

- [How to Remove Internet Explorer and Outlook Express from your Computer.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192852)
- [Windows-XP - Uninstall Outlook Express](http://www.activewin.com/tips/tips/microsoft/winxp/advanced/8.shtml)

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler, but thanks for answering the question.